# Does channel videos work with channel form

Tags: safecracker, channel-videos

I am trying to add an SAEF for members to upload videos and currently have channel videos, does anyone know if it works and what the template code would be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done this some time ago, I thought by using this code which generates all you need in your form. Docs here https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#other-channel-fields
(edit: 2015-02-10 This worked for me EE  v.2.7.2 Channel Videos v. 3.1.5)

```
{exp:channel:form channel="video" return="edit-embed/wijzig-video/ENTRY_ID/upload-success" entry_id="{segment_3}"}
{field:youtube}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Comment: that' what i thought but it doesn't work. It just displays {field:videos}

Comment: Hi I am sorry this did not work for you. I copied my code above in the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I have fixed that part now, I had been creating a few channel forms and forgot to change the channel name so now I get submit video url etc.  But when I click on submit Video Url, enter the url and click ok nothing happens.

Comment: Can you use Channel Videos in the CP using the same methode?

Comment: Yes it works fine.